# Moonlight on MAC OS X

Tags: mono, moonlight

I am not able to build Moonlight application on MAC OS X.

the error sates: Framework "Moonlight/Silverlight 3.0' not installed.

Can anyone help me out with this

Comment: I take it this is using monodevelop?  MD only supports moonlight 2.0 afaik